# reader read multiple in one connection C#

Tags: c#

I have this code snippet

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.WPC_AppConnectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT engid,shop_order,hours_,work_date FROM engineer WHERE entry_=" + textBox2.Text.ToString();
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        textBox4.Text = reader["engid"].ToString();
        textBox6.Text = reader["shop_order"].ToString();
        textBox8.Text = reader["hours_"].ToString();
        dateTimePicker3.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["work_date"].ToString());
    }
}
```

When I run this its suppose to use a textBox to get entry_ ( in this case lets say 3) Then select the columns from my sql table and fill out the other textboxes it crashes with

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckDataIsReady(Int32     columnIndex, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn, Boolean permitAsync, String methodName)
  InnerException:
```

It works fine when i separate each one out to its own sql connection but I was wondering if I can combine into one.

my table looks like
entry_ | 3
engid | NAME
shop_order | NUMBERS
hours_ | 1
work_date | 01/01/0001

I'm fairly new to C# and i did some research but couldn't quite find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround your while statement with braces like this.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    textBox4.Text = reader["engid"].ToString();
    textBox6.Text = reader["shop_order"].ToString();
    textBox8.Text = reader["hours_"].ToString();
    dateTimePicker3.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["work_date"].ToString());

}
```

because in your case while loop runs only first line and when while loop ends the other lines run. so the exception occurs.